# How to enable JSON calls in my ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to make a dynamic chart using HighCharts, but as it seems to be, is impossible to include ASP tags inside a JavaScript, so I'm trying to use JSon. I followed [this tutorual](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=399) step-by-step, but when I try to load the page, I get the following message:

> This request has been blocked because
>   sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites
>   when this is used in a GET request. To
>   allow GET requests, set
>   JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

So now I'm wondering if I have to set something in `Web.Config` or somewhere else.

Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty simple fix.  In your request-handling functions, where you would have:

```
return Json(myStuff);
```

Replace it with the overload that takes a `JsonRequestBehavior`:

```
return Json(myStuff, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```